# How to set automatically highlite.js style for all pre tag

Tags: highlight.js

Everyone 
I am making blogging site using quill.js. To view post in frontside I am using highlite.js.

In following image first 2 block are displayed with default side just `<pre>` tag.
and last one with `<pre><code class="dart">{code}</code></pre>`

My question is

1. I don't want to add manually html with `<code class="dart">`
2. I want automatic set styling by using just  tag

I read all document but not found any specific answer how to set?
please any one?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer. Using custom selector.

```
   document.querySelectorAll('pre').forEach((block) => {
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
   });
```